# Suspicious case statement syntax accepted by C compilers

Tags: c, syntax, compiler-errors

I found a long-standing bug is some code (I had written the code, so my it's own fault). The thing that I cannot understand is why it was not spotted by the compiler.

The code is in C, which I have been using for many years and I always consider myself knowledgeable about, but it makes no sense to me. I have tried similar code under both Visual Studio and Gnu C compilers and both accept it.

The code is:

```
enum TYPE_ENUMS {
    TEST_CASE = 1,
};

int main()
{
    int caseVal = 1;
    switch (caseVal) {
    TEST_CASE:
        printf("1\n");
    default:
        printf("Unknown Case %d\n", caseVal);
        break;
    }   
}
```

Can anyone explain how an enum can be part of a case statement without a "case" before it.
Should this be valid code? and if so, is there a use for it?

Comment: It's not a case, it's a label.

Answer (score 4):

What you have is actually a **label** that can be the target of a `goto` statement, and there's no restriction that says ordinary labels can't appear inside of a `switch` block.

Labels are in a separate namespace from ordinary identifiers which includes `enum` constants, so they can coexist without ambiguity.  This is spelled out in section 6.2.3p1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> If  more  than  one  declaration  of  a  particular  identifier  is
> visible  at  any  point  in  a translation  unit,  the  syntactic
> context  disambiguates  uses  that  refer  to  different  entities.
> Thus, there are separate *name spaces* for various categories of
> identifiers, as follows:
>
> - *label names* (disambiguated by the syntax of the label declaration and use);
> - the *tags* of  structures,  unions,  and  enumerations  (disambiguated  by  following  any of the keywords `struct`, `union`, or `enum`);
> - the *members* of  structures  or  unions;  each  structure  or  union  has  a  separate  namespace for its members (disambiguated by the type
>   of the expression used to access the member via the `.` or `->`
>   operator);
> - all other identifiers, called *ordinary identifiers*(declared in ordinary declarators or as enumeration constants).

Answer (score 2):

It *is* valid code but, perhaps, not in the way you think. There is no error in your code but both MSVC and Clang-cl (in Visual Studio 2019) give warnings that indicate your `TEST_CASE:` line is simply an independent (of the `switch`) label.

Clang gives these:

> warning : unused label 'TEST_CASE' [-Wunused-label]
>  warning :
> code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]

(The latter for the `printf("1\n");` line)

MSVC gives this, in addition to equivalents of the above two warnings:

> warning C4065: switch statement contains 'default' but no 'case'
> labels

If there is a 'moral to the story', it is this: **Enable full compiler warnings!**

Comment: The moral is actually "Enable and clear all warnings" :)